# Want to integrate Shiprocket APi to create a custom order in PHP/ Laravel

Tags: laravel

I tried to integrate shiprocket api through curl to create custom order, but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

use this Laravel package its very easy to use https://github.com/seshac/laravel-shiprocket-api